# Kustomize fails to process secretGenerator, with kubectl it works though

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have an overlay `kustomization.yaml` as following:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

bases:
    - ../../base/

patches:
    - patch.yaml

secretGenerator:
    - name: my-secrets
      env: password.env
```

When applying it with embedded `kustomize` on `kubectl` like `kubectl -k` it works fine, but now I need to generate the final yaml before applying it so when I attempt to use itself through `kustomize build devops/kustomize/my-cluster/overlay/local > local.yaml` I'm getting this error:

```
Error: json: unknown field "env"
```

`secretGenerator` spec has `env` parameter so I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe you are using old version of kustomize. Also you could try running `kubectl -k` with `-oyaml --dry-run >> local.yaml`

Comment: kubectl is using an old version of kustomize; since then `env` parameter was changed to `envs`

Answer (score 5):

Turns out that newer versions of kustomize use `envs` parameter instead of `env`